# The goal is to pass the PageSpeed test https://prnt.sc/T0edUHFsx3lC

Tags: optimization, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights, mod-pagespeed, cls

Before that, they worked with the domain https://alterair.ua/
Performed the scope of work recommended by PageSpeed Insights and passed the test (mobile and desktop) https://prnt.sc/IsUJW8kek_y7

List of completed works:

1. Optimized and compressed js files (as far as possible)
2. Fixing css
3. Corrected classes and tags of picture styles
4. Added width and height for images in the menu
5. Moved responsive.css to scss
6. The main menu has been optimized
7. Added apia tags to all links that did not have href
8. Updated version of jquery
9. Fixed user-scalable
10. Fixed image elements not having clear width and height for some mobile versions
11. Refinement of captcha loading logic (captcha loading at the moment of opening the folder, not when loading the page).

At the moment, exactly this scope of work was performed on the domain https://shop.alterair.ua/, but we are not passing the check!

One of the hypotheses is a problem in Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS), because according to the main domain, the performance is only 42, but the mobile test passes https://prnt.sc/oQeu7f62sW56, while on the desktop (CLS) it has fallen, the performance is 75+ https:/ /prnt.sc/QFWm4A85ahjl and the check stopped going through (a month ago everything was fine).

1. Could you analyze https://shop.alterair.ua/ and provide recommendations on the solution?
2. How can we increase the Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) if this is really the problem?
3. Is there any tool to see the Core Web Vitals Assessment result in real time instead of waiting for 28 days?

Comment: Some of us in the web performance community analyzed your site and added our findings to this thread: https://community.perfplanet.com/t/cls-issues-on-a-ukrainian-hvac-website/98

Answer (score 0):

It seems your main issue isn't CLS ( At 0 right now ) but the LCP, due to an image not sized correctly.